# std::list.sort(), binary predicate?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, std

I have a list container class (not the `std::list`) that can store any
type. I want to store many `std::listS` in this container with
different types(`list<int>`, `list<string>` etc.).

Can I use a generic binary predicate when I am sorting them?

Pseudo code:

```
template <typename T>
bool compare(const T& input1, const T& input2)
{
    return input1>input2;
}

for(auto i = myList.begin(); i!=myList.end(); ++i) //i is an iterator to a std::list
{
    (*i).sort(compare<decltype(*i)::value_type>);
    //when dereferencing i I get a
    //std::list
}
```

Is this valid (I am not really sure if I can use decltype this way)?

The problem is I can't get even this simple example to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void display(const T& input)
{
    for(auto i = input.cbegin(); i!=input.cend(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

template <typename R>
class SomeFunc
{
public:
    bool operator ()(const R& in1, const R& in2)
    {
        return in1>in2;
    }
};

template <typename R>
bool someFunc(const R& in1, const R& in2)
{
    return in1<in2;
}


int main()
{
    list<int> myList;
    myList.push_back(5);
    myList.push_back(137);
    myList.push_back(-77);
    display(myList);
    myList.sort(SomeFunc<decltype(myList)::value_type>());
    display(myList);
    myList.sort(someFunc<decltype(myList)::value_type>);
    display(myList);

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;

};
```

**Correction:**
It does compile here: http://ideone.com/ZMcjSJ
Not on my VS2012 though... I'm starting to hate VS. Can anybody clarify a possible reason why it wouldn't compile on VS2012? I obviously have the decltype command in VS2012 but I suppose it doesn't work like a C++ 11 dectype would work?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

I tried it in CodeBlocks with gnu gcc set to C++ 11 - works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the method [`std::list<T>::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/) has an overload which takes a comparison functor:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyComparator
{
    bool operator() const (const T& input1, const T& input2)
    {
        return input1 > input2;
    }
};
...
myList.sort(MyComparator<T>());
```